# Blazor - Singleton callback lambda breakpoints not hit

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a lambda callback for a Singleton/Transient/Scoped services that configures additional options on Blazor Server-side code.

The breakpoints are mysteriously not hit when the application starts up. What is happening?

Example:

```
services.AddSingleton<BlobContainerClient>(sp =>
{
    var config = sp.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(); //breakpoint here - not hit on startup
    var azureStorageContainer = config["AzureStorageContainer"];
    return sp.GetRequiredService<BlobServiceClient>().GetBlobContainerClient(azureStorageContainer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline services are lazy loaded in certain cases - actually activating the Dependency Injection is required to hit the Action callback defined in the lambda.

So, in the example, the a back-end service must be called that injects the service requested before the breakpoint will be hit - so actually nothing is wrong.

E.g.

```
public class ApiController : ControllerBase
{
    public ApiController(BlobContainerClient _bcc) {

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void TestBcc() {
      //when this method is hit, the breakpoint will activate
    }
}
```